# How to access GAE datastore property with variable usage instead of actual name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a number of lines like

```
if last_name:
    person.last_name = hashlib.sha512(last_name + salt).hexdigest()
if first_name:
    person.first_name = hashlib.sha512(first_name + salt).hexdigest()
```

I would like to write a function to simplify the code. But how can I use `person.<variablename>?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def set_hash(entity, name, value):
  if value:
    setattr(entity, name, hashlib.sha512(value + salt).hexdigest())


set_hash(person, "last_name", last_name)
set_hash(person, "first_name", first_name)
```

Comment: Change one of the `name` or `attr_name` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to enumerate properties individually like in Shay's example, a much more readable solution is to just abstract your code into a function:

```
def poorly_salted_hash(value, salt):
  return hashlib.sha512(value + salt).hexdigest()

person.first_name = poorly_salted_hash(first_name, salt)
person.last_name = poorly_salted_hash(last_name, salt)
```

If you're wondering why I'm calling the function "poorly salted hash", that's because this isn't a good way to salt a hash: you should use a construct like HMAC, which is provided by the Python `hmac` library. It's rather odd - to say the least - to be hashing someone's first and last names, though, so I don't know what your security goals are here.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your suggestion. This is not what I am looking for, but anyway it is good to know.

Comment: @LA_ If you're using the code as Shay demonstrates it, there's absolutely no reason to be using `setattr`.